# apply a normal python function to pyspark df

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, pyspark

```
def cleanTweets(text):
    text = re.sub(r'@[A-Za-z0–9]+','', text) #remove the mentions
    text = re.sub(r'#','', text) # remove the #
    text = re.sub(r'RT[\s]+','', text) # remove the RT
    text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/\S+','', text) #remove hyperlink
    return text


tweets_df_cleaned = tweets_df.withColumn('Tweets',col(udf(cleanTweets(Text))))
```

how could i apply this to the tweets_df which has a column Text to clean, in pandas it can be done by apply

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

```
tweets_df['Tweets_New'] = tweets_df['Tweets'].apply(cleanTweets)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas UDF(User-Defined Function). Check your spark version because this solution is for Spark 3.X version.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

def cleanTweets(text):
text = re.sub(r'@[A-Za-z0–9]+','', text) #remove the mentions
text = re.sub(r'#','', text) # remove the #
text = re.sub(r'RT[\s]+','', text) # remove the RT
text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/\S+','', text) #remove hyperlink
return text

@pandas_udf("string", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
tweets_df_cleaned = tweets_df.withColumn("Tweets", cleanTweets("text"))
```